# API should return data in JSON but not shown in layout

Tags: android, api, runtime-error, retrofit

I am trying to pass my json response to an adapter class, i am getting response from the rest api but still the json object array is not passing to the adapter class after the retrofit handler class converts the json response into object array. i am not getting any log error or warning but when i try to use this activty in my android app i am getting no results.

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppBaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.history_header)
    RelativeLayout history_header;

    @BindView(R.id.history_list)
    ListView history_list;

    @BindView(R.id.no_history_view)
    LinearLayout no_history_view;

    @BindView(R.id.hdr_back)
    TextView hdr_back;

    private String address;
    private String category;
    private String distance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        unbinder= ButterKnife.bind(this);
        backBtnSet();

        updateHeader();
        Intent intent=getIntent();

        if(intent!=null && intent.hasExtra("mid")){
            String mId=intent.getStringExtra("mid");

            address=intent.getStringExtra("address");
            category=intent.getStringExtra("category");
            distance=intent.getStringExtra("distance");

            fetchHistory(mId);
        }else {
            activityFinish();
        }
    }

    private void backBtnSet() {

        final int height= (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp_24);
        hdr_back.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        Drawable img = getBaseContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.ic_backarrow);
                        img.setBounds(0, 0, height,
                                height);
                        hdr_back.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
                        hdr_back.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateHeader() {
        TextView hView= history_header.findViewById(R.id.hdr_title);
        hView.setText(getString(R.string.history_small));
    }

    private void fetchHistory(String mId) {
        JsonObject jObject=ParamConvertor.getCustomerHistory(userInfo.getId(),
                userInfo.getAccessKey(),mId);

        Call<ArrayList<HistoryCustomer>> call=apiService.getCustomerHistory(jObject);
        call.enqueue(new RetrofitHandlerFull<ArrayList<HistoryCustomer>>(this,
                networkHandler,1));
        AppLogger.printPostBodyCall(call);
    }
//Problem persists from here  
    private INetworkHandler<ArrayList<HistoryCustomer>> networkHandler
            = new INetworkHandler<ArrayList<HistoryCustomer>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(ArrayList<HistoryCustomer> data, String msg, int num) {
            if(data!=null && !data.isEmpty()){
                updateList(data);
                dataPresent(true);

            }else{
                dataPresent(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String msg, int error) {
            dataPresent(false);
        }
    };

    private void updateList(ArrayList<HistoryCustomer> data){
        HistoryAdapter adapter=new HistoryAdapter(this,data,
                address,category);

        history_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private void dataPresent(boolean isPresent){
        if(isPresent){
            no_history_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            history_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            no_history_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            history_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.hdr_back)
    void onCLicks(View view){

        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.hdr_back:
                activityFinish();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, it seems fine to me can you check your endpoint which you are calling may be it might returning null or empty object.